# How to get LoginPath when using ASP.NET Core 2 authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am registering authentication for .NET Core ASP.NET app in a standard way:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(o => o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Auth/Login"));
    // ...
}
```

How can I get this value down the road for usage? Say I have some logic in controller and want to have path to Login page for whatever reason... like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index() {
        var loginUrl = ...;

        // ...
    }
}
```

How would I get `loginUrl` in this example?

Answer (score 2):

Assign the login path to a constant value in another static class. Then build the url using the Request object properties inside your action:

var loginUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{Constants.LoginPath}"

The above will be a string but you can create a Uri if needed.

Comment: And here I was trying to think through the usage of framework when `const string` would suffice. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

For `LoginPath`, you could try `IOptionsMonitor<CookieAuthenticationOptions>` like below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly CookieAuthenticationOptions _cookieAuthenticationOptions;
    public HomeController(IOptionsMonitor<CookieAuthenticationOptions> optionsMonitor)
    {
        _cookieAuthenticationOptions  = optionsMonitor.Get(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var loginPath = _cookieAuthenticationOptions.LoginPath;
    }        
}
```

Comment: This almost worked for me, had to make a small change, I'm on asp.net core 3.1.
`_cookieAuthenticationOptions = optionsMonitor.Get(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);`.